# Display vertical axis individual chart labels in google column chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am using google column chart for a while and I want to display the vertical columns value at top of each column. I am able to get the tool tip value but my requirement is not concerned with the tooltip.

Is there any way to display column values at top of each column so that it is easier to visualize? I looked at the options but couldn't get to make this work.

Here is the link for column chart that I am using
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart

Comment: It seems that such feature isn't provided out of the box. You can write your own code which will create several div elements and calculate their position. Or use some other chart framework, jqPlot for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is highly sought after, but unfortunately still not supported by Google Charts.

After long striving with this, I've made a hack to the `ComboChart` (could work with `BarChart` and `ColumnChart` as well, with a couple of changes) to insert the labels into the SVG.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/augustomen/FE2nh/

Tested on Firefox 21, Chrome 27 and IE 9.